How to add a new function to a dotnet-isolated (net8.0) function app using Azure Functions Core Tools?
I want to add a new function to my dotnet-isolated (net8.0) function app project using Azure Functions Core Tools, but I'm getting the following error:
Intialize function app project:
func init --worker-runtime dotnet-isolated --target-framework net8.0 --docker

Add new function:
func new --language c# --template "Timer trigger" --name UpdateApplications
Selected language doesn't match worker set in local.settings.json.Selected worker is: dotnetIsolated and selected language is: dotnet

How can I add new C# functions to my function app?

To add a new function, remove --language c# in the command func new --language c# --template "Timer trigger" --name UpdateApplications.
I have created the Timer Trigger .NET 8.0 isolated Azure function using below commands:
1. func init --worker-runtime dotnet-isolated --target-framework net8.0 --docker
2. func new --template "Timer trigger" --name UpdateApplications



local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}

UpdateApplications.cs:
public class UpdateApplications
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public UpdateApplications(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<UpdateApplications>();
        }

        [Function("UpdateApplications")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            
            if (myTimer.ScheduleStatus is not null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
            }
        }
    }

Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

Response:
Functions:

        UpdateApplications: timerTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-09-06T09:20:14.269Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-09-06T09:25:00.107Z] Executing 'Functions.UpdateApplications' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-09-06T14:55:00.0494065+05:30', Id=913778fb-b3a2-496b-a53a-158293318108)
[2024-09-06T09:25:00.243Z] Next timer schedule at: 9/6/2024 2:55:00 PM
[2024-09-06T09:25:00.243Z] C# Timer trigger function executed at: 9/6/2024 2:55:00 PM
[2024-09-06T09:25:00.273Z] Executed 'Functions.UpdateApplications' (Succeeded, Id=913778fb-b3a2-496b-a53a-158293318108, Duration=211ms)


Thank you. But what template language is used then? The language is C#, so why can't I use C# then?

As you have initialized the project with .NET 8.0 isolated using command func init --worker-runtime dotnet-isolated --target-framework net8.0 --docker, you don't have to mention the worker language again. You can directly create the function with the required trigger template

But why does it fail, if I mention that language?

When you initialize the function with command func init --worker-runtime dotnet-isolated --target-framework net8.0 --docker, it creates all the files with dotnet-isolated runtime. As per my observation, when you specify c# as the language in the command, it defaults to using the in-process dotnet function runtime and it will look for dotnet FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME in local.settings.json. Since the file has dotnet-isolated as runtime, the command is failing.

I have tested by changing the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME to dotnet in local.settings.json. I could run the command func new --language c# --template "Timer trigger" --name AddApp and create a new function. Image1, Image2.

If you want to create dotnet isolated function, run func new --language c# --template "Timer trigger" --name AddApp directly without running func init command. Refer Image.
